# Extending a controller function within directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a `cancel` function in my controller that I want to pass or bind to a directive. This function essentially clears the form. Like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    var self = this;

    self.cancel = function(){...
        $scope.formName.$setPristine();
    };
}]);

app.directive('customDirective', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        scope: {
            cancel : '&onCancel'
        },
        templateUrl: 'form.html'
    };
});
```

form.html

```
<div>
    <form name="formName">

    </form>
</div>
```

However, the $setPristine() don't work as the controller don't have access on the form DOM. Is it possible to extend the functionality of controller's `cancel` within the directive so that I will add `$setPristine()`?

Some suggested using jQuery to select the form DOM, (if it's the only way) how to do that exactly? Is there a more Angular way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `<form>` is inside the directive, the controller should have nothing to do with it. Knowing it would break encapsulation, i.e. leak implementation details from the directive to the controller.

A possible solution would be to pass an empty "holder" object to the directive and let the directive fill it with callback functions. I.e.:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    $scope.callbacks = {};

    self.cancel = function() {
        if( angular.isFunction($scope.callbacks.cancel) ) {
            $scope.callbacks.cancel();
        }
    };
});

app.directive('customDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        scope: {
            callbacks: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'form.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.callbacks.cancel = function() {
                scope.formName.$setPristine();
            };

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                delete scope.callbacks.cancel;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Use it as:

```
<custom-directive callbacks="callbacks"></custom-directive>
```

I'm not sure I am OK with this either though...

Comment: Should I use `'='` in `scope` instead of `'&'`? I read somewhere that expressions should use `'&'`.